# IndentationErro and NameError and new function error(cant print out after using def)

Tags: python, sqlite

Before adding function of my program, it works and print out my commands in my sqlite3 db

but after adding def

it looks like

```
def readswitch(x,y,read):

x='create vlan'
y='global'
conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')

with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
    # function = "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =:function or type =:type　ORDER BY key ASC",{"function":x},{"type":y}
    # function = ("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?　ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
read = cur.fetchall()
for row in read:
     print (readswitch())
```

It shows that `x='create vlan'IndentationError: expected an indented block`

After i press tab press space bar

it has a error like that:

```
def readswitch(x,y,read):

    x='create vlan'
y='global'
conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')

with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
    # function = "SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =:function or type =:type　ORDER BY key ASC",{"function":x},{"type":y}
    # function = ("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?　ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
read = cur.fetchall()
for row in read:
     print (readswitch())



cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

what should i do now?

---

now I fixed this problem
and face other function error

I remove the `def(readswitch(x,y,read):` it has no error and can print out my command.

```
x='create vlan'
y='global'
conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')

if conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        for row in read:
             print (row)

# def update()
```

But after i add back my `def(readswitch(x,y,read):` and i change the `print(row):`
it prints nothing

```
def readswitch(x,y,read):

    x='create vlan'
    y='global'
    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')

    if conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        for row in read:
             print (readswitch())
```

Any one has some ideas on it?
    `

Comment: `x` is local variable for function `readswitch()`.  And all code code in inside `readswitch()` function ??

Comment: @Vivek Sable yes, maybe there are sth i miss to do !If you have idea pls tell me and i will correct now thank you so much

Comment: move all  code inside readswitch() function

Comment: remove it from x='create vlan' to print (readswitch())?? Really?

Comment: what is `with` statement? means if `conn` is True then you want to run code??

Comment: @ Vivek Sable idk I just study from website and copy it! now i remove it but it is not the main problem of IndentationError: expected an indented block and NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: can u check solution which I given ??

Comment: there is right remark left side of my answer.. below the upvote remark.  :)

Comment: Thank you and welcome. let me know if you need more help. You can reach to me by email(vivekbsable@gmail.com) or skype (vivek.igp) also

Comment: @ Vivek Sable also can you help me to fix some function problem? I will update in this queston as i cant ask question in 90MINs

Comment: ok, I think you can ask different question. this is over.

Comment: Can  you print `conn` value? and what is ` print (readswitch())` ??

Comment: change print statement to print row but before that print value of `conn` variable.

Comment: thank you later i will answer one more question and accept your answer after my asking period!  But I still cant print out an command, is it my logic flow problem??

Comment: Print `conn` variable value before if statement, also print type of `conn` variable.  e.g `print "value of conn", conn`     `print "type of conn", type(conn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation issue with some statements are at wrong place.

```
def readswitch(x,y,read):

    x='create vlan'
    y='global'
    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')

    if conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        for row in read:
             print row
```